# Can reading from SQLite table give an error while simultaneously it is being renamed?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a requirement in which I have to use two tables `main` and `tmp` . **main** is the table that have to be used always so my query is like

`Select * from main;`

**tmp** is created in background parallely. As soon its created, I want this DB db to be used. Hence, I will rename **tmp** to **main** so that now **tmp** becomes the default DB in use and the existing SQL queries need not be modified.

1. Now, my question is can I get an error like *table not found* while I am renaming the tables?

Comment: Why not giving it a shot first..

Answer (score -2):

SQLite [is transactional](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html), i.e., as long as the two table modifications are done in a single transaction, it will work fine.